# Python How to Access Com Port / Serial / Usb from other Computer in the same local network

Tags: python, pyserial

I have serial device which connected to my computer (PC) . The device is connected via USB-Serial cable and is assigned COM1 port. my computer has IP 192.168.2.120 and my laptop IP is 192.168.2.110, both connected in same network using router.

how i can access the port COM1 in my computer(PC) from my laptop?

i try this code :

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial("COM1",9600,timeout=1)


while (True):

    if ser.isOpen():

        input_data=ser.readline()
        value = str(input_data)
        value1 = value.split("   ")
        value2 = value1[1].split("\\r\\n'")
        value_final = value2[0]
        print(value_final)
        # print(value2)
```

Comment: I think you would need to make a virtual serial port of some sort, there is no way to directly connect to another PCs serial port using the serial API

Comment: is it possible to combine between pyserial and pysocket?